# Android : Calendar view different in API 22 vs API 23

Tags: android, calendarview

I'm developing an appointment app, and the user is presented with a calendar to choose the date. So I included a CalendarView, but when I run the app on different API levels, the CalendarView is displayed diffrently.

API 23 :

[image]

API 22 and below :

[image]

XML code :

```
<CalendarView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/calendar"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appointment_toolbar"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Is there a way to display the CalendarView in the same format for both APIs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html):

> The exact appearance and interaction model of this widget may vary
>   between OS versions and themes (e.g. Holo versus Material), but in
>   general a user can select a date by tapping on it and can scroll or
>   fling the calendar to a desired date.

So I don't think it's possible. But you can use some third party library to pick a date.

Comment: Think so .Perfect answer

Answer (score 4):

The calendar view **depends on the theme and the OS**, however the basic function is to pick a date , so the appearance may vary. If you want to have the same appearance across all versions of android, you can use a third party CalendarView. Try https://android-arsenal.com/tag/27.

Answer (score 1):

May this way work.
Find the source code of CalendarView and copy it to your programe ,then use it replace the source CalendarView